# ard-float version of the libspotify for ARMv7

Tags: spotify, libspotify

At the moment, we are trying to integrate the latest libspotify release 12.1.51 eabi-armv7.
This library has been developed for a soft-float kernel running on ARM7.

We are using a more recent hard-float kernel on our platform, requiring a hard-float version of the libspotify for ARMv7.
The  hard-float release offered by spotify is for ARM6, so we can’t use it.

Any idea on how to get this?

Answer (score 1):

ARMv6HF libraries should work just out of the box on ARMv7HF systems.

It will not take use of some instructions that's available on the v7 CPU but apart from that it should work just fine.